# pseudo captcha to download a vcard from a static (html+javascript) only page...how?

Tags: javascript, captcha, vcf-vcard

i set up a simple personal page that shows some personal information
of mine. I included a vcard download. Now, the amount of spam I am getting has increased considerably.
Its a simple page, static only, no php.
How can I "hide" the vcard for it to be downloaded only by human beings?
I suppose it would require the human to do something a spam harvester doesnt do. Press a button maybe? Also, how can I hide the path of the vcard from the html so that its not obviously in there.
thanks,
-gk
PS.- I am not a programmer, so please be gentle with the explanation :) . thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a javascript link to open the vcard would help (I've no idea what a vcard is but I'm assuming its a file!)

```
<a href="http://www.myhomepagetothrowthebots.com" onclick="window.open(path/to/my/vcard.whatever); return false;">click here</a>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea. Yes, the vCard is a small file with my contact information in text form. The problem with this, is that the URL "path/to/my/vcard.whatever" is there in the html....wouldnt the spam harvester see that and just "click" it itself? Is there a way to obfuscate that path a bit? thanks, -gk

Comment: Sure a simple obfuscator should do the trick: http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/obfuscator.php, (just take care to remove the mailto: prefix in this one)

Comment: perfect! thanks! I suppose i would use something like this then (combining your first suggestion with this one)

Answer (score 1):

If it's in your page, even if it is hidden, a bot can easily see your source code and grab your data.

The options are:

- Use an image so it's not readily machine-readable (but this negates the value of a v-card).
- Use Javascipt to load it based on user interaction. (as cusimar proposes)

Comment: the image wouldnt work. The whole point is to be able to download the vcard directly into outlook, iphone, etc. Are there any other options you can think of? thanks. -gk